# Cursor FETCH failed. @@FETCH_STATUS is -1

Tags: sql-server

Transactions table definition :

```
create table Transactions ([ID] [int] NOT NULL, [Value] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Let's insert some records.

```
INSERT INTO Transactions Values(1,100)
INSERT INTO Transactions Values(2,10)
```

This is how I am using cursor

```
create table #Tmp_Transactions ([ID] [int] NOT NULL, [Value] [int] NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #Tmp_Transactions SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE Value>100
DECLARE @rowcount int
SET @rowcount = @@rowcount
PRINT @rowcount
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE txcursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM #Tmp_Transactions
OPEN txcursor
FETCH NEXT FROM txcursor INTO @ID
PRINT @@FETCH_STATUS ---//prints -1

CLOSE txcursor
DEALLOCATE txcursor
drop table #Tmp_Transactions
```

----- prints

```
(0 row(s) affected)
0
-1
```

Comment: You **also** need to replace `SELECT * INTO` with `INSERT INTO #Tmp_Transactions SELECT * FROM Transactions etc.`

Comment: No effect. It still returns -1

Comment: How many rows do you have in #Tmp_Transactions? Do you have any rows? As per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fetch-status-transact-sql#return-value), status `-1` means `"The FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set."`

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu None. Why?

Comment: There it is, your code works, except that you have no data for your cursor to go over and retrieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after opening cursor, you have to use FETCH..like below

```
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
```

since you are not doing that,Fetch_status will be -1

**Updated as per changes in question:**

There is no result set due to this `WHERE Value>100`,so you are getting -1.When you use >=100,there is a result set and you will not see fetch status `-1`

Comment: That's not the problem. I missed FETCH statement in my question. I still have the problem even after putting FETCH NEXT as you suggested. I have edited the question.